# In Java Regular Expression "\1" (back reference) is not working

Tags: java, regex

I want to replace string `"Cannot"` with `"Can not"` and `"cannot"` with `"can not"`. For that, I am using the code below:

```
 String string = "I Cannot do it.";
 string = string.replaceAll("([Cc])annot", "\\1an not");
```

Desired string is `"I Can not do it."`.

```
String string = "I Cannot do it.";
string = string.replaceAll("([Cc])annot", "\\1an not");
```

Desired string is `"I can not do it"`. In Ruby `'\1'` replaces a string with the matched character `C` or `c` (using back reference). I don't know what to use in Java. Below is the Ruby regex which works fine:

```
"I Cannot do it".gsub!(/([Cc])annot/,'\1an not')
# => "I Can not do it"       
"I cannot do it".gsub!(/([Cc])annot/,'\1an not')
# => "I can not do it"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about

```
String string = "I Cannot do it."
string = string.replaceAll("([Cc])annot","$1an not");
```

Answer (score 4):

Try saying:

```
string = string.replaceAll("([Cc])annot","$1an not");
```